# Failure on initialization of unordered map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, unordered-map, clang++

and thanks for any input. I have a large dataset I am trying to manipulate. I am holding active elements in a list, and removing them when they become inactive. I want to hold all elements active and inactive in some data structure. Currently trying a map or an unordered_map, but am welcome to any suggestions.

I am compiling with

> clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra

When trying map:

```
#include <map>
std::map <class1, std::string> fullMap;
//and later...
for (std::list<class1>::iterator x = l.begin(); x != l.end(); x++)
{
    fullMap[(*x)] =  s
}
```

output reads:

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const class1' and
>   'const class1') { return __x < __y; }

Even though I have overloaded the less than operator for class1.
This error originates at the overloaded bracket operators for map.
To circumvent I tried storing in an unordered_map.

```
#include <unordered_map>
std::unordered_map <class1, std::string> fullMap;
```

and the program fails at the initialization of fullMap with the even more confusing:

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.4/include/g++-v4/bits/hashtable_policy.h:830:23:
>   error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
>   'std::hash'
>              bool __use_ebo = !__is_final(_Tp) && __is_empty(_Tp)>
>                                ^
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.4/include/g++-v4/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1073:15: note: in instantiation of default argument for
>   '_Hashtable_ebo_helper<1, std::hash >' required here
>         private _Hashtable_ebo_helper<1, _H1>,
>                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.4/include/g++-v4/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1403:12: note: in instantiation of template class
>   'std::__detail::_Hash_code_base >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
>   std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>' requested here   : public
>   _Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _H1, _H2, _Hash,
>              ^
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.4/include/g++-v4/bits/hashtable.h:175:14:
>   note: in instantiation of template class
>   'std::__detail::_Hashtable_base >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to, std::hash,
>   std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
>   std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash,
>         std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits >' requested here
>       : public __detail::_Hashtable_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal,
>                ^
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.4/include/g++-v4/bits/unordered_map.h:100:18:
>   note: in instantiation of template class 'std::_Hashtable >,
>         std::allocator > >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to, std::hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
>         std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy,
>   std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits >' requested here
>         _Hashtable _M_h;
>                    ^
>
> main.cpp:34:44: note: in instantiation of template class
>   'std::unordered_map,
>   std::hash, std::equal_to,
>   std::allocator > > >' requested here   std::unordered_map  fullMap;
>                                              ^
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.4/include/g++-v4/bits/functional_hash.h:58:12:
>   note: template is declared here
>       struct hash;

I tried to cut the code down only to the relevant chunks, but let me know if more information is needed. Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated.

```
//
//  class1.hpp
//  class
//
//  Created by Roach on 9/3/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Roach. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef class1_hpp
#define class1_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>


class class1
{
public:
  class1 ();
  class1 (const class1& t); // copy constructor
  ~class1 (); // destructor
  class1& operator = (const class1& t); // assignment operator
  bool operator == (const class1& t); // comparison operator
  void setSetting2 (std::string t);
  void setSetting1 (std::string p);
  void setSetting3 (double d);
  void setSetting4 (double d);
  std::tm getTime () const;
  std::string getSetting2 () const;
  double getSetting3 () const;
  double getSetting4 () const;
  std::string getSetting1 () const;
  void setSetting3End (double d);
  void setSetting4End (double d);
  double getSetting3End () const;
  double getSetting4End () const;
  double getSetting3flag () const;
  double getSetting4flag () const;
  double getSetting3final () const; // in pips
  double getSetting4final () const; // in pips
  void processList (class1::class1 t);
  void setNew ();
  //void dump (std::ostream& os) const;

private:
  std::string setting1;
  double setting4;
  double setting3;
  std::tm setting2;
  double setting4End_;
  double setting3End_;
  bool setting4Flag_;
  bool setting3Flag_;
  double setting4final_; // in pips
  double setting3final_; // in pips
};
// stream extraction operator
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const class1& s);
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, class1& t);

endif /* class1_hpp */
```

The following is my overloaded less than operator (I know it isn't the most succinct or efficient):

```
bool class1::operator< (const class1& t)
{
  if (this->time_.tm_year < t.time_.tm_year) {return true;}
  else if (this->time_.tm_year > t.time_.tm_year) {return false;}
  else if (this->time_.tm_mon < t.time_.tm_mon) {return true;}
  else if (this->time_.tm_mon > t.time_.tm_mon) {return false;}
  else if (this->time_.tm_mday < t.time_.tm_mday) {return true;}
  else if (this->time_.tm_mday > t.time_.tm_mday) {return false;}
  else if (this->time_.tm_hour < t.time_.tm_hour) {return true;}
  else if (this->time_.tm_hour > t.time_.tm_hour) {return false;}
  else if (this->time_.tm_min < t.time_.tm_min) {return true;}
  else if (this->time_.tm_min > t.time_.tm_min) {return false;}
  else if (this->time_.tm_sec < t.time_.tm_sec) {return true;}
  else {return false;}
}
```

Comment: Well, you probably didn't declare the relevant operations necessary to use your type as a map key.

Comment: Can you post the interface for `class1`? Also, what's the definition of `l`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I have overloaded assignment, equality, less than, stream extraction and insertion, as well as all the usual constructors. Is there something I am missing I am not aware of?

Comment: @templatetypedef I will post header file as edit at bottom of the post in a few min. Also 'l' is a std::list

Comment: Re: "I tried to cut the code down only to the relevant chunks, but let me know if more information is needed": Yes: what's needed a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is a pretty confusing question. The code shows a `std::map`, but the error clearly comes from an `std::unordered_map`. It's basically impossible to tell what's wrong, since we don't see any of the relevant code.

Comment: The first error is likely due to the lack of a properly defined `operator<` overload for your `class1` (`std::map` requires it for key comparison). And the second error is due to not specifying a hash function-object for `class1`, which is required for `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @ruakh, thanks for the link. Will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury, I hadn't thought of that for unordered_map. I have added my overloaded less than at the end of my post, please let me know if I'm handling it wrong.

Comment: You need to mark `class1::operator<` as `const` to be able to use as the key comparator for `std::map<class1, Type>`.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury you are the man! add as answer and I will accept.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but in modern C++ you can replace all that copy-pasting on the comparison operator by having a function (or lambda)  `auto tied_tm(std::tm const &a) { return std::tie(a.tm_year, a.tm_mon, a.tm_mday, a.tm_hour, a.tm_min, a.tm_sec); }` and then your comparison operator body is simply `return tied_tm(time_) < tied_tm(t.time_);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `std::map<key_type, value_type>` requires a properly defined `operator<` for `key_type`, in this case your `operator<` is not `const` specified so it is incompatible with `std::map` as this data structure requires that the comparator not alter the key object in any way. Thus the solution is to mark `class1::operator<` as `const`.

The second error notes that no hash function-object has been applied for use with `std::unordered_map`, this would require the following framework:

```
auto class1_hasher = [](const class1& c) -> std::size_t { return {some hash based on c}; }
std::unordered_map<class1, std::string, decltype(class1_hasher)> um;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that you're breaking the preconditions required of the `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` interfaces.

In a `std::map`, the key type needs to be able to be compared using the less-than operator. This means that you either need to provide an overload of `operator <`, or provide a custom comparator when you're using the `std::map` type. Since you didn't provide a way of doing this with your type, the internal implementation of `std::map` wasn't able to make an expression of the form

```
 somethingOfTypeClass1 < somethingElseOfTypeClass1
```

compile, hence your error message.

When you switched to `std::unordered_map`, you ran into trouble because, in order to store something as a key in an `std::unordered_map`, you need to specialize the `std::hash` template on your custom type because the internal works of an `unordered_map` require that the type is hashable. That's the second error you got.

To fix this issue, either

1. Define a custom `operator <` or comparator type for `class1`, then use `std::map`, or
2. Define a custom `std::hash` for `class1`, then use `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help. Although I don't have the hash function for the unordered_map defined, I do have an overloaded less than operator which is why I don't understand why std::map isn't working. I've added it at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: @Zroach Make your `operator<` `const` - `bool class1::operator< (const class1& t) const` and your `std::map` should work.

Comment: @Paul, you are correct, ArchbishopofBanterbury suggested that above in comments on my post and that was the answer. Waiting for someone to include this in the answer to mark as solved, though I guess this answer will do with these comments attached. Thanks paul.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to suggest best data structure until we know the functionality requirement. But the Below code is working for me on GCC 4.9.3.
Please check your include files and syntax.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//LIST
std::list<int> myList;
myList.push_front(1);
myList.push_front(2);
myList.push_front(3);
myList.push_front(4);    

//STRING
string s = "Test";

//MAP    
std::map <int, std::string> fullMap;   
for (std::list<int>::iterator x = myList.begin(); x != myList.end(); x++)
{               
    fullMap.insert(std::make_pair(*x,s));

}

//UNORDERED MAP    
std::unordered_map <int, std::string> fullUnorderedMap;   
for (std::list<int>::iterator y = myList.begin(); y != myList.end(); y++)
{        
     fullUnorderedMap.insert(std::make_pair(*y,s));
}

//PRINTING    
for(auto it = fullMap.begin(); it != fullMap.end(); ++it)
{

    cout<<it->first<<"       "<<it->second<<endl;

}

for(auto it = fullUnorderedMap.begin(); it != fullUnorderedMap.end(); ++it)
{

    cout<<it->first<<"       "<<it->second<<endl;

}
```

}

Comment: With the code updated in the question it looks like the issue is that the key type in the map didn't support the proper operations. You're using `int` keys, which do support all the necessary operations, hence the lack of errors.

Comment: I agree. He should overload comparator operator.